# How to compare Negative numbers in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to compare validation range in between -180 to 180 .
If number is less than -180 and greater than 180 then it should show error.

I have written below code for this -

```
 if((markerPoint[0] && parseInt(markerPoint[0],10) < -180 || parseInt(markerPoint[0],10) > 180)) {
        this.latlngError.push("Invalid coordinates");
    } else {
        this.isLanLngValid = true;
    }
```

But this is returning incorrect comparison.

Comment: Also note that `0` is a `falsey` value...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Math.abs()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs) instead:

```
if (markerPoint[0] && Math.abs(parseInt(markerPoint[0],10)) > 180)
```

Edit: As noted by @TedHopp, the visible issue with your current code seems to be operator precedence. `&&` has [higher precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) than `||`. Using [Math.abs()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs) bypasses the issue.

If that doesn't solve the problem, then more code needs to be supplied for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to compare validation range in between -180 to 180

For number between -180 and 180 the number must be greater then -180 and less then 180, so change the comparison.

```
if(markerPoint[0] && parseInt(markerPoint[0],10) > -180 && parseInt(markerPoint[0],10) < 180) {
```

Answer (score 0):

try this [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nisr19/w6hhpgja/)

```
var answer = prompt("type a number");
func();
function func() {
  if (answer>=-180&&answer<=180) {
    alert("Yes! We made it!");
  } else {
    answer = prompt("Invalid try agian");
    func();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Replace below code it will work for sure.**
if(markerPoint[0]>=-180 && markerPoint[0]<=180)

Answer (score 0):

One problem with your code is that in JavaScript `&&` has higher precedence than `||`. (See the table [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence).) Thus, the logic is evaluated as if it were parenthesized:

```
if (
    (markerPoint[0] && parseInt(markerPoint[0],10) < -180)
    ||
    parseInt(markerPoint[0],10) > 180)
{
```

You can use parentheses to change that:

```
if(markerPoint[0] && (parseInt(markerPoint[0],10) < -180 || parseInt(markerPoint[0],10) > 180)) {
```

Then the `if` test will pass if `markerPoint[0]` is a truthy value and if it evaluates to something outside the range [-180, 180].